# pytroch data loader RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [224, 224] at entry 0 and [224, 224, 3] at entry 1

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, pytorch-dataloader

my problem is i got two tensors in one dataset with headers image and label[image]

when i execute simple loop all look fine
unfortunetly when i make dataloader as below

```
training_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=100, shuffle=True)
```

and run

```
for i in training_loader:
print(i)
```

Im getting error:

RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [224, 224] at entry 0 and [224, 224, 3] at entry 4

what can cause it and how to fix it ? thank you inadvance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like one (or more) of your images is not a color image, but a gray-scale image.
Modify your loading code to force all images to be treated as color images:

```py
img = Image.load(filename).convert('RGB')
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58497441/1714410) for more details.