# How to load first 2 channel of a 3 channel image in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, resnet

I have a datasets of 3 channel images, but I want to use the first 2 channel of each image as input to Resnet34. Is there anyway I can just load the first 2 channel of each imgage?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. Images on disk have 3 channels, and you need to remove one when you load them using your `Dataset`.
2. Your network (`ResNet-18`) expects inputs with 3 channels - now it will get only two. (This might trigger an error like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58497441/1714410)).

You can solve both issues by keeping the third channel but setting it to zero.
This can be easily achieved using a custom augmentation:

```py
class ZeroThirdChannel(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def __call__(self, x):
    x[2, ...] = 0  # set the third channel to zero
    return x
```

Add this augmentation to your `Dataset`'s `transforms` *after* `ToTensor()`.

Comment: does this need a `class` keyword?

Comment: I'm saying you gave code that is supposed to define a python class. it's gotta be introduced using the `class` keyword to be valid python. there. I just did that myself. should have done that to begin with.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you for your correction. I misunderstood your first comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question,  does setting the third channel to zero gets the same classification accuracy as sending a two channel tensor to resnet?

Comment: @BEJ how are you going to pass a two-channel image to a pretrained 3-channel ResNet?

Comment: I've seen some research works that put 2 channel tensor into resnet to get trained, and I'm trying to make comparison with these works by just using 2 channel of my image. But I'm not sure if setting one channel as zero can gets the same result.